# How would I put this set of javascript if statements with varying IDs and Values in one smaller statement?

Tags: javascript, beginner

I'm wanting to reduce the amount of code in this set of statements, as it seems quite repetitive:

```
        if ($('#Size').val() === 'extra-cab' && $(this).attr("id") === 'canopy-17x-select') {
            $('.rack-kit input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
        }
        if ($('#Size').val() === 'double-cab' && $(this).attr("id") === 'canopy-17x-select') {
            $('.rack-kit input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
        }
        if ($('#Size').val() === 'double-cab' && $(this).attr("id") === 'canopy-14x-select') {
            $('.rack-kit input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
        }
```

There are three statements. The first Size statement has a value of 'extra-cab' and the next two statements have a value of 'double-cab'. The first two statements share the same ID attribute, but the third one is different.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the if statements ? you do one work in every if statement. `$('.rack-kit input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');` is same in all conditions so just put `$('.rack-kit input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');` with no conditions.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `if (['extra-cab', 'double-cab', 'double-cab'].includes($('#Size').val()) && $(this).attr('id') === 'canopy-14x-select') { $('.rack-kit input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked', false).trigger('change'); }` Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest things for this is to create a method and create parameter for all those different value.

```
function triggerChange(sizeVal, canopyId){
    if ($('#Size').val() === sizeVal && $(this).attr("id") === canopyId) {
        $('.rack-kit input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
    }
}
triggerChange('extra-cab', 'canopy-17x-select');
triggerChange('double-cab', 'canopy-17x-select');
triggerChange('double-cab', 'canopy-14x-select');
```

You could also use parameter to send some flag for different condition.

```
function triggerChange(sendTrigger, sizeVal, canopyId){
    if (sendTrigger && $('#Size').val() === sizeVal && $(this).attr("id") === canopyId) {
        $('.rack-kit input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
    }
}
```